# Formatting Array full of URL's into iframes

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array full of URL's, heights and widths I'd like to format into a div. I've been told it can be done with a foreach loop but unfortunately I am unfamiliar with how to use this properly. I'm very much so a novice when it comes to coding. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
dl = [
    'dashlet1' => [
        'url' => 'http://1.1.1.1:1288/stff/db/?6',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ],
    'dashlet2' => [
        'url' => 'http://1.1.1.1:1288/stff/db/?8',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        "width" => 'width=450'
    ],
```

Comment: RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: show how should look the final divs

Comment: The final format would be something like this.
```<div>
<iframe src="http://1.1.1.1:1288/stff/db/?6" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really try it for yourself before asking for help, but anyway here is an idea to get you started:

```
foreach($array as $element)
{
    $url = $element["url"];
    $height = $element["height"];
    $width = $element["width"];
}
```

Assuming your actual PHP array is like this:

```
$array = array(
    'dashlet1' => array(
        'url' => 'http://1.1.1.1:1288/stff/db/?6',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        'width' => 'width=450'
    ),
    'dashlet2' => array(
        'url' => 'http://1.1.1.1:1288/stff/db/?8',
        'height' => 'height=200',
        "width" => 'width=450'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, my main problem is always getting started. I can normally edit/modify anything seen to what I want but starting it has always been difficult for me.

Comment: No problem, there is documentation on all PHP features: http://php.net/manual/en/index.php with examples if you ever need future help